# Restart remote client machine

Tags: remote-desktop, reboot

All client machine's connected to server via open vpn. Also all of the client machine has set custon winlogon shell settings, To run only myapp.exe.
So, the desktop or anyother explorer cannot be visible unless from taskmanager by using ctrl_shift_esc.

One of the client machine has stopped the myapp.exe, and wanted to restrt the machine. So from server done an RDP using open vpn IP, But unfortunately ctrl_shift_esc is not working to start the taskmanager. 
Is there any way to restart this client machine from server machine. As no other tool is available in server to restrt this machine. They connected only via openvpn.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PowerShell is enabled on the target machine you can remotely reboot it with powershell command.

```
PS C:\> Restart-Computer <hostname or IP> -whatif
```

Also you can restart multiple computers in single line of command

```
PS C:\> Restart-Computer "hostname1", "hostname2"  -whatif
```

If someone logged in to target computer you can use -force parameter to force reboot.

> -WhatIf parameter is used to verify the command.

please have a look at this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849837.aspx

Comment: shutdown -i and by adding the ip of the machine to the reboot window has solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The less sophisticated yet time-proven solution is to use the free handy utility called [Wizmo by GRC](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) (the same guy who made ShieldUp)

Once downloaded and deployed, you can cause a reboot via calling,

```
wizmo reboot
```

- Note: not `wizmo restart`. because it's so easy, you can create a shortcut, or add it to PATH and call from the terminal. Too easy!